# Setting axis limits on pandas scatter_matrix from editor vs console

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

With pandas scatter_matrix, I set my axis limits to something different than scatter_matrix defaults to. See the following code in editor:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,2), columns=list('AB'))

axarr = pd.scatter_matrix(df)
axarr[0,1].set_ylim(-10,10)
axarr[0,1].set_xlim(-10,10)
```

This works. However, when I try to do the same from the console, it does NOT update the axis limits. That is, if i type

```
>>>> axarr[0,1].set_ylim(-100,100)
```

the plot just stays the same.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after you update the plot in the console (I'm assuming you're using ipython with the `%matplotlib` magic command), you just need to call `plt.draw()` to update the figure. You will need to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` too.

So:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [4]: %matplotlib

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,2), columns=list('AB'))

In [6]: axarr = pd.scatter_matrix(df)
```

[image]

```
In [7]: axarr[0,1].set_ylim(-10,10)
Out[7]: (-10, 10)
In [8]: axarr[0,1].set_xlim(-10,10)
Out[8]: (-10, 10)

In [9]: plt.draw()
```

[image]

```
In [10]: axarr[0,1].set_ylim(-100,100)
Out[10]: (-100, 100)
In [11]: plt.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: Allright.... but, why? Why do you need to call plt.draw() from console where this is not necessary fromout the editor?

Comment: I am using Spyder on Windows